# JSON.parse no realiza su función. xmlHttpRequest - Api rest Wordpress - Javascript

Tags: ajax, json, wordpress, xmlhttprequest, endpoint

He creado un **Endpoint** en **wordpress** para realizar la consulta de ciertos datos a través de ***XMLHTTPREQUEST*** con la finalidad de poder actualizar el contenido de la web de manera automática sin necesidad de refrescar la página a través de un filtro.

La cosa es que consigo extraer los datos del **Endpoint** pero me los devuelve como un **string**, cuando utilizo **JSON.parse** no me genera el **objeto javascript** para tratar los datos devueltos sino que me sigue marcando que es de tipo **string** si lo compruebo a través ***typeof()***.

Adjunto código que devuelve los datos del Endpoint.
*(Posiblemente esté aquí el error de como enviar los datos correctamente, en mi opinión)*

```
function filtradoFrontPage($data){

                if($data['id'] == 10101010101010 ){
                    $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'meta_key' => 'post_views',
                        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                        'order' => 'DESC'
                    );
                    $popular_posts = get_posts($args);
                    $postArray = [];
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($popular_posts as $post){
                        $pT = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
                        $pN = $post->post_name;
                        $pL = get_permalink($post->ID);

                        $postArray[$i] = array(
                            'name' => $pN,
                            'thumbnail' => $pT,
                            'link' => $pL
                        );
                        $i++;
                    }
                    $data = JSON_ENCODE($postArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
                    return rest_ensure_response($data);
                    }
                }
```

Esta es la forma en la que intento recibir los datos que se envían del Endpoint.

```
function filtroXMLHttpRequest(parametro){

        let param = parametro;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.responseType = 'text';
        xhttp.onload = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
                var data = xhttp.responseText;
                var dataJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                document.querySelector('.swiper-wrapper').innerHTML = "";
                for(let i = 0; i < dataJSON.length; i++){
                    let divSlide = document.createElement("div");
                    let articleSlide = document.createElement("article");
                    let spanSlide = document.createElement("span");
                    let aSlide = document.createElement("a");
                    divSlide.appendChild(articleSlide);
                    articleSlide.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url("+dataJSON['thumbnail']+")");

                    document.querySelector(".swiper-wrapper").appendChild(divSlide);
                }
            }
        };
        let url = 'http://paginaweb.local/wp-json/filtro-front-page/v1/posts/id='+param;
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

Si necesitáis alguna explicación más decidme.